# A simple example with OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm following the next tutorial in order to run my first OpenCL program.
https://medium.com/@pratikone/opencl-on-visual-studio-configuration-tutorial-for-the-confused-3ec1c2b5f0ca

The result of summation, however, is not 1024 in my case, as it should be. The sum of two numbers equals 0 (Release) or -842150451 (Debug) in my case. That is, a part of the output looks like  this:

> 1000+24 = 0
>
> 1001+23 = 0
>
> 1002+22 = 0

My display adapter is Nvidia Geforce 8400. The installation of CUDA SDK has also finished successfully.

Here are source files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
 
int main(void) {
    printf("started running\n");

    // Create the two input vectors
    int i;
    const int LIST_SIZE = 1024;
    int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        B[i] = LIST_SIZE - i;
    }
 
    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;
 
    fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );
    printf("kernel loading done\n");
    // Get platform and device information
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;   
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    
    
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &ret_num_platforms);
    cl_platform_id *platforms = NULL;
    platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(ret_num_platforms*sizeof(cl_platform_id));

    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(ret_num_platforms, platforms, NULL);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[1], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, 
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);
    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
 
    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);
 
    printf("before building\n");
    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, 
            (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);
 
    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    printf("after building\n");
    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);
 
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);
    printf("ret at %d is %d\n", __LINE__, ret);

    //added this to fix garbage output problem
    //ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(int), &LIST_SIZE);
 
    printf("before execution\n");
    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
            &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
 printf("after execution\n");
    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
    int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), C, 0, NULL, NULL);
 printf("after copying\n");
    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);
 
    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    return 0;
}
```

**vector_add_kernel.cl**

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C) {
 
    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0);
 
    // Do the operation
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

Comment: when I change this: `ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[1]...`  to this: `ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0]...` your code works correctly for me.  8400 is a really old GPU.  What GPU driver do you have loaded and what CUDA SDK version did you install?

Comment: Version of the driver is 342.01 released on 14 Dec 2016, version of CUDA SDK is 9.1. Changing of that line in the code doesn't work for me.

Comment: CUDA SDK 9.1 won't work with that GPU which is very old.  Try using CUDA SDK 6.5

Comment: Now it works. Thank you!